# remove pop up box only if login successfull

Tags: magento-1.8

we are hiding the pop up once we click on login "button", but we want to hide only if the login is successfull. [ if user enter correct email id & password ]

> Login Form

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect.....>

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" />
<label>password</label>
<input type="password" name="login[password]"  id="pass" />

<button onclick="hideWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
```

> controllers

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }
            // echo $login['product_id'];die;
            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());


                    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();
                    // To save inside my_designs

                    return $product;                   

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);

                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();
                    /
                }
            // } else {
            //     $result['error'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Login and password are required.');
            // }
        // }

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

        // code for guest end
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ajax call on button click and check in call that if customer is got logged in. You can manage the popup display as per the ajax response from controller.